# Getting the title of a page in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, title

I'm trying to get the title of a page in an iFrame. I did look at some other questions on stackoverflow and found the following code:

```
var title = $("#frame").contents().find("title").html();
alert(title);​
```

I though it should work.

But here on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/6TAhg/) the code doesn't seem to work. Can anyone explain to me why it wont work, and give me a suggestion of how I would get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross domain, so the parent javascript will get nothing from iframe content when iframe loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iframe+domain). You can't access the contents of another domain from your domain. It would be a security risk.

Comment: and I did say I saw other posts. Just SAYING! -_-

Comment: lol, yeah I read it but you weren't looking for the right terms that's why I put the search link.

Answer (score 0):

```
        (function(el, w)
{
    function loadFunc(e)
    {
        e = e || w.event;
        var f = e.target || e.srcElement, fb = f.contentDocument || f.contentWindow.document;
        document.title = fb.title;
    }
    if (w.addEventListener)
        el.addEventListener('load', loadFunc, false);
    else if (w.attachEvent)
        el.attachEvent('onload', loadFunc);
})
(document.getElementById('myIframe'), window);
```